# Rails console not working with redgreen gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console, redgreen

I have a problem with rails console, here is what I am getting when I try to start rails console:

> backo@speedy:~/ucimrails/simple_app$ rails c --sandbox
>   /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- test/unit/ui/console/testrunner (LoadError)
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/redgreen-1.2.2/lib/redgreen.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`each'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`each'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in`require'
>     from /home/backo/ucimrails/simple_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in`require'
>     from /home/backo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
>     from script/rails:6:in`require'
>     from script/rails:6:in `'

I located the problem is caused by redgreen gem. When I exclude it from Gemfile, console works again. But, can someone help me to make it working with redgreen gem? Interesting is that this is only happening on my netbok, when I work on my desktop computer all is fine with rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'
```

...seems to work for me with 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8.  It would, however, be nice to use this with a more recent version of test-unit (looks like 2.5.2 is the latest right now)...

Answer (score 0):

The redgreen gem doesn't work with 1.9.2; for redgreen test output you might try

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'   

class Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner
  def guess_color_availability; true; end
end
```

in your test helper or so.

Comment: Doing this doesn't seem to change anything for me.

Comment: Hmm, it certainly works here. Did you specify test/unit in your Gemfile or are you relying on test/unit bundled with ruby 1.9?